# What is the correct Accuracy for the missile launcher weapons in Run and Gun?

Tags: weapons, shadowrun-sr5, shadowrun, errata

Run and Gun contains two new missile launcher weapons: the Onotari Arms Ballista MML and the Mitsubishi Yakusoku MRL.

Both are listed as having Accuracy "Missile". This is wrong, because Missiles (and Rockets) don't actually have Accuracy scores. Missile launchers are supposed to get their *damage* ratings from the missile, but are supposed to have their own Accuracy score.

For comparison, the core book launchers have Accuracy scores of 5, for the Aztechnology Striker; and 4 (6), for the Onotari Interceptor with integrated smartlink.

The available errata for Run and Gun doesn't address this question.

I would prefer a cited official answer if any has been published outside of the errata document. Second best would be a semi-official answer from whoever wrote that part of the book (with citation). Third best would be an argument-from-fluff, or prior edition weapon stats, as to what the Accuracy scores "should" be for these weapons.

Comment: Not even the german book that I own contains the answers.... Something wenn horribly wrong there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally the german book [got it's errata (german forum)](http://www.foren.pegasus.de/foren/topic/22968-kreuzfeuer-errata-sammelthread/page-6#entry486010) for the second edition of Run & Gun ("Kreuzfeuer").

The Onotari Arms Ballista MML has an accuracy of 4(5).
The increased accuracy is possibly a result of using the included laser designator as a laser sight.

The Mitsubishi Yakusoku MRL has an accurcy of 4(6).
The increased accuracy comes from it's internal smartgun system.